# Can this be simplified?

Tags: scala, types

Referring to a [previous answer of mine on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026055/mixing-in-generic-traits-in-parameterized-classes-without-duplicating-type-parame/5028335#5028335)

The core of the complexity is illustrated in just one method:

```
implicit def traversableToFilterOps[CC[X] <: Traversable[X], T]
(xs: CC[T])(implicit witness: CC[T] <:< TraversableLike[T,CC[T]]) =
  new MoreFilterOperations[CC[T], T](xs)
```

With two questions:

1. Is there any way to give the compiler a hint that `Map` meets the signature `CC[X] <: Traversable[X]`?
   I would expect it to match as a `Traversable[Tuple2[_,_]]` but this doesn't happen.  In the end, I had to write a second method taking `CC[KX,VX] <: Map[KX,VX]`, but that feels redundant
2. `witness: CC[T] <:< TraversableLike[T,CC[T]]` also seems redundant given the first type parameter, my gut feeling is that this is enforced by the type of `Traversable` and must *always* hold true for any possible subclass or value of `X`, so there should be no reason to explicitly require it as a witness.

If I test this using an existential type in the REPL, then the compiler seems to agree with me:

```
scala> implicitly[Traversable[X] <:< TraversableLike[X,Traversable[X]] forSome { type X }]
res8: <:<[Traversable[X],scala.collection.TraversableLike[X,Traversable[X]]] forSome { type X } = <function1>
```

Is there therefore any way to do away with the boilerplate?

Comment: The answer lies somewhere in here: https://gist.github.com/445874

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Scala noob, so please don't shoot me down if this doesn't help.

Assuming this:

```
class MoreFilterOperations[Repr <% TraversableLike[T,Repr], T] (xs: Repr) {}
```

Would something like this work?

```
// t2fo is short for traversableToFilterOps
implicit def t2fo[Repr <% TraversableLike[T, Repr], T](xs: Repr) = 
  new MoreFilterOperations[Repr, T](xs)

// m2fo is short for mapToFilterOps
implicit def m2fo[Repr <% Map[K, V] <% TraversableLike[(K,V), Repr], K, V]
  (xs: Repr) = new MoreFilterOperations[Repr, (K, V)](xs)
```

This should work because (according to the book I have.. Programming Scala, p264) the following method definition with a view bound:

```
def m [A <% B](arglist): R = ...
```

It is effectively the same as this method definition:

```
def m [A](arglist)(implicit viewAB: A => B): R = ...
```

Comment: So don't even bother checking for `<: Traversable` in the implicit methods, and cut straight to `<% TraversableLike`. I like it... simple, and certainly sounds plausible for this particular use case. It doesn't help answer the broader question of subclassing in implicits, but still a great idea. now to fire up the REPL and confirm :)

Comment: Perhaps the bounds `X <: A <% B` would answer your question about subtyping? Since it should accept any `X` that is a subtype of `A` that has a view in scope that transforms it to a `B`.

Comment: It's not a complete answer, but you get the green tick anyway for being constructive and adding something of value.